# In Ruby, How to read UTF-8 from a socket?

Tags: ruby, sockets, utf-8

When a server sends UTF-8 bytes, how do you read them without characters becoming pure bytes? (\x40 etc)

Comment: A combination of IO::select() and IO#read_nonblock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `read_nonblock` uses [`read`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO#read-instance_method), which in turn says:

> The resulted string is always ASCII-8BIT encoding.

Which means you don't need to specify `IO#set_encoding`, but that you can, after you read **whole** string, force its encoding (using `String#force_encoding!`) to `UTF-8`.

I emphasized 'whole', as you need to make sure that you read entire Unicode character at the end of the string, as if only part of it is read, you will get invalid UTF-8 character and Ruby might complain about it further down the line.

Comment: This is not completely true any more, but still in some cases: “In the case of an integer length, the resulting string is always in ASCII-8BIT encoding.”.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [IO#set_encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-set_encoding) to set a socket's external encoding to UTF-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

require 'socket'

server_socket = TCPServer.new('localhost', 0)
Thread.new do
  loop do
    session_socket = server_socket.accept
    session_socket.set_encoding 'ASCII-8BIT'  
    session_socket.puts "  ᚁ ᚂ ᚃ ᚄ ᚅ ᚆ ᚇ ᚈ ᚉ ᚊ ᚋ ᚌ ᚍ"
    session_socket.close
  end
end

client_socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', server_socket.addr[1])
client_socket.set_encoding 'UTF-8'
p client_socket.gets
# => "|  ᚁ ᚂ ᚃ ᚄ ᚅ ᚆ ᚇ ᚈ ᚉ ᚊ ᚋ ᚌ ᚍ\n"
```

Comment: Would IO#set_encoding work if I'm reading the bytes off of a socket one-by-one with #read_nonblock?

Comment: @lcarpenter, I don't see why not.  Have you tried it and found that it doesn't?

Comment: well, #gets would work, but with read_nonblock and a buffer, it doesn't

Comment: \u0080 is two characters wide, but if I read one byte, it comes up as "\xC2", then if I read another char, it shows as "\x80"

Comment: One thing I did notice is that #set_encoding doesn't actually translate the two bytes into the one "\u0080" char, meaning I have to do it manually with #ascii_only? :/

Comment: @lcarpenter, Mladen's got the answer to that.